# How can the client stay waiting for a possible server message?

Tags: android, sockets, client, inputstream

I'm a newbie so I'm sorry if I ask dumb questions. 
I have to do a socket connection with a server.
The client (the android device) has to send a message to the server and to wait for an ack message. Then the server, if it doesn't receive nothing from the client for 30 seconds, sends a request for an ack message.
What I've done it's the first part: the client sends the message and read the response.
What I ask it is: How can the client wait for a possible message from the server?
This is the code I wrote:


In onCreate method:

```java
Thread myThread = new Thread(new myRunnable());
myThread.start();
```

And this is myRunnable:

```java
public class myRunnable implements Runnable{
  public void run(){
    try{
      Socket socket = new Socket(serverIp, serverPort);
      InputStream is = socket.getInputStream();
      OutputStream out = socket.getOutputStream();
      out.write(byteBuffer.array());
      out.flush();
      byte[] bbb = new byte[1024];
      // Receive message from server
      int bytesToRead= is.read(bbb);
      is.close();
      out.close();
      socket.close();
```

Successives read operations return -1, so how can I stay waiting for a server message?
Thank you very much for any advices.

Comment: do not put tags in subject: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/should-questions-include-tags-in-their-titles

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You shouldn't close streams. Your communication with server closes when you close streams. Usually server communication happens in infinite loop. Something like this:

```
public class myRunnable implements Runnable{
  public void run(){
    try{
      Socket socket = new Socket(serverIp, serverPort);
      InputStream is = socket.getInputStream();
      OutputStream out = socket.getOutputStream();
      out.write(byteBuffer.array());
      out.flush();
      byte[] bbb = new byte[1024];
      while (true) {
         // Read next message.
         bytesToRead = is.read(bbb);
         // handle message...
         // If you need to stop communication use 'break' to exit loop;
      }
      is.close();
      out.close();
      socket.close();
```

So thread stops on line `bytesToRead = is.read(bbb)` until server sends any message, after that it handles message any way you want and got back to reading next message. If you need to stop communication exit loop using `break`.

Comment: Thank you for the answer! I tried as you tell me but I don't receive nothing more than the first message and "bytesToRead" is always = -1. I read in this answer: [link](http://stackoverflow.com/a/611777/1696856) that "A read of -1 doesn't mean, "there's no data present on this attempt," it means, "the stream is closed and there will never be any data so stop asking." I don't know what I should do! Thanks

Comment: Are you sure server didn't close connection?

Comment: Is there a way to know that? with method isConnected()?

Comment: Hm, try it. I don't know :\

Comment: I accepted your question now, I finally found that it was my error: I sent to the server a byteBuffer with one more byte than the length of the message, so the server closed the connection. Thank you for reply