# Is there any way to perform an action on stream input?

Tags: java, listener, inputstream

Is there any way to listen to a stream input and perform an action like read() whenever a new byte is available?

Answer (score 0):

By default `read()` method blocks in open streams till a new input is provided.
 You don't need to do any actions.
Read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/611777/2703795)
If you mean that blocking until new input receives is not desired, create a separate `Thread` or `Fiber` to do that for you.