# EOF alert values of IO classes

Tags: java, eof

I have a question about the IO classes of Java.

The classes that ending with Reader return the int of the read char.

The classes that ending with Stream return the value of byte of the read byte (from 0 to 255).

So, I don't understand why for the Reader the EOF alert value is -1 and for Stream is null. Why?

Thanks a lot!

A.

Comment: Hope this solves your problem. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/611760/java-inputstream-blocking-read

Comment: Well, [`Reader.read()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/12/docs/api/java.base/java/io/Reader.html#read()) and [`InputStream().read()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/12/docs/api/java.base/java/io/InputStream.html#read()) both return -1 at the end of input, so there is no difference.

Comment: Where did you see that the EOF value for Stream is null?